# urllib3 using an ssh connection as proxy

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, proxy, urllib3, telepot

I have an ssh connection as below in my local laptop:

`ssh -f -N -D 3232 USER@IP`

now in `telepot` which using from `urllib3` i want to pass all connections to this ssh connection because `Telegram` servers has been banned in my office.
I read [this](https://github.com/nickoala/telepot/issues/83) and do what it said. but when I use this:

`proxy_url = 'http:localhost:3232`

I get this error:

`urllib3.exceptions.ProxyError: ('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f22968e5710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))`

How can i connect to this server?

Comment: You could maybe try an ssh tunnel, rather than a proxy.  You can set it up so you connect to the local port of the tunnel, and ssh passes it through to the destination.  http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use older version of `urllib3` you ,ust upgrade it using `sudo pip install urllib3 --upgrade`.
Then you must install `PySocks` using `sudo pip2 install PySocks`.
After these two steps you must change the code [here](https://github.com/nickoala/telepot/issues/83) to this:

```
proxy_url = 'socks5://localhost:PORT'

telepot.api._pools = { 
            'default': SOCKSProxyManager(proxy_url=proxy_url, num_pools=3, maxsize=10, retries=False, timeout=30),
            }

telepot.api._onetime_pool_spec = (SOCKSProxyManager, dict(proxy_url=proxy_url, num_pools=1, maxsize=1, retries=False, timeout=30))
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't find `SOCKSProxyManager`, use the below import:

```
from urllib3.contrib.socks import SOCKSProxyManager
```